# Betragsangabe in Währung/der die das?

Tags: gender

Wenn man über einem Betrag spricht, welchen Genus nutzt man?

```
[der die das] 10 Euro?
```

z.B:

> kann man **den** 10 Euro online bezahlen?

Comment: Bitte die vorhanden Auszeichnungsmöglichkeiten nutzen, nicht "den(?) 10 Euro". Und "10 Eur" lässt sich im Deutschen gar nicht sprechen :) .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Es sind mehrere Euro, daher

> **die** zehn Euro

der Euro, die Euro/die Euros. Steht auch im Wörterbuch.

Comment: verstehe ich dann so: in der Regel muss man auf die Währung / Einheit achten..

Comment: Richtig. Es waren z.B. früher *die eine Mark, die zehn Mark, die eine dänische Krone, die zehn dänischen Kronen*.

Comment: Aber der Dollar, Denar, Taler, Franc.